# Error creating bean with name 'functionBindingRegistrar'

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

My application is failing to start with the below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'functionBindingRegistrar' defined in
 org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration: Invocation of init
 method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
 Discovered 3 methods that would qualify as 'functional' - [public boolean 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean.equals(java.lang.Object),
 public java.lang.String org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean.toString(), 
public int org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean.hashCode()].
\n Class 'class org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean' is not a FunctionalInterface.\n\tat
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced with the issue, but with my own class, not Spring's.

My class implemented `Consumer<>` functional interface. I removed it, but left the config in `application.yml`:

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=*bean_name*
```

So, in my case simple removing the above config helped.

But if there is no such config in your `application.yaml` or you really need the above config, then according to the [answer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/issues/887#issuecomment-1209526633) the following config's addition might be helpful:

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.autodetect=false
```